# Changing font type in Matplotlib Axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I need to change the font type of my `ylabel` and `xlabel`:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.rand(50)
Y = X + np.random.rand(50)*0.1

results = sm.OLS(Y,sm.add_constant(X)).fit()


plt.scatter(X,Y)

X_plot = np.linspace(0,1,100)
plt.plot(X, results.fittedvalues, color = 'red')
plt.ylabel('$x_2$')
plt.xlabel('$x_1$')
plt.show()
```

[image]

But i need x1 and x2 to look like this:

[image]

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/font_family_rc_sgskip.html

Comment: If you want to use LaTeX for rendering the text, please see: [Text rendering with LaTeX](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html)